# React Native - There is no route defined for Login

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm learning to react native by configuring tabNavigator, DrawerNavigator, and StackNavigator into one without NativeBase or Expo with a single react-navigation library.

I achieved it but there was an error when I performed some specific sequence in my application.

The application starts with a Tab Screen. -> Change Tab -> Open Drawer -> Goto Stack -> Open Drawer and then go to Tabs gives this error.

Here is my code :

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Drawer} from "./src/navigation/MergedNavigator";
import {View,Text} from "react-native";

const App = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#293656'}}>
        <Drawer />
    </View>
);

export default App;
```

**MergedNavigator.js**

```
import {DrawerNavigator,StackNavigator,createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

// stack navigation screens
import DetailScreen from '../screens/detail';
import MainScreen from '../screens/main';
import ForgotScreen from '../screens/ForgotScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen';

// tab navigator screens
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import TabOne from '../screens/tabA';
import TabTwo from '../screens/tabB';

//plain

export const stack = StackNavigator({
    DetailScreen:{screen:DetailScreen},
    MainScreen:{screen:MainScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'DetailScreen'
});

const secondStack = StackNavigator({
    RegisterScreen:{screen:RegisterScreen},
    ForgotScreen:{screen:ForgotScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'ForgotScreen'
})

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Login:{screen:LoginScreen},
    TabOne:{screen:secondStack},
    TabTwo:{screen:TabTwo}
},{
    animationEnabled:true
})

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Tabs:{screen:Tabs},
    Stack:{screen:stack}
})
```

All other imported stack screen has nothing but the title.
What's the problem here with my code? Or is there any better way I can achieve these all 3 Navigators with only react-navigation?

Comment: Should your Drawer have a Login key?

Comment: @Colin Sorry, but i didn't understand what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the **sub actions** being reset inside the **Stack** which can be seen [**here**](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/4237/files)

Therefore the workaround for this issue would be to wrap your `createBottomTabNavigator` inside a `createStackNavigator` with `headerMode: none` in order to achieve the desired effect.

### Info

By adding a **StackNavigator** nested directly within a **DrawerNavigator**, the sub actions will be reset only to the **StackNavigator** defined and won't affect the child screen states, therefore it won't throw the error, as mentioned in the [**code**](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/4fe72f662730ed4b6b3cbd37890982a591630922/src/views/Drawer/DrawerSidebar.js#L65)

```
if (route.index !== undefined && route.index !== 0) {
   subAction = NavigationActions.reset({
   index: 0,
   actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route.routes[0].routeName,
   }),
  ],
 });
}
```

### MergedNavigator.js

```
import ForgotScreen from '../screens/ForgotScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen';

// tab navigator screens
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import TabOne from '../screens/tabA';
import TabTwo from '../screens/tabB';

//plain

export const stack = StackNavigator({
    DetailScreen:{screen:DetailScreen},
    MainScreen:{screen:MainScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'DetailScreen'
});

const secondStack = StackNavigator({
    RegisterScreen:{screen:RegisterScreen},
    ForgotScreen:{screen:ForgotScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'ForgotScreen'
})

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Login:{screen:LoginScreen},
    TabOne:{screen:secondStack},
    TabTwo:{screen:TabTwo}
},{
    animationEnabled:true
})

const TabStack = createStackNavigator({ //... Adding the Stack here
  Tabs: {screen: Tabs}
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
})

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Tabs:{screen:Tab},
    Stack:{screen:stack}
})
```

[Here's](https://snack.expo.io/@pritishvaidya94/test-navigation) a modified Snack with header's enabled

Comment: then how can i navigate to other page from tab and still display header..? I Tried many things but it still won't display.
Do you have any solution or perfect demo?

Comment: The `headerMode: none` should only disable the header of that particular stack, the others would remain unaffected. You can add the issue with relevant details to the question, i'll take a look when i'll be available.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let { navigation } = this.props;
let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    key: undefined,
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'YourScreen' })],
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

When you set the key to undefined, the navigator uses the actual stack, not the root.

Answer (score -1):

First of all your main issue is you cann't create more than one StackNavigator() on your code.

Please try different navigator for redirection like below example code.

```
import {DrawerNavigator,StackNavigator,createBottomTabNavigator,createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

// stack navigation screens
import DetailScreen from '../screens/detail';
import MainScreen from '../screens/main';
import ForgotScreen from '../screens/ForgotScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen';

// tab navigator screens
import * as TAB from '../tab';

export const stack = StackNavigator({
    DetailScreen:{screen:DetailScreen},
    MainScreen:{screen:MainScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'DetailScreen'
});

const secondStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    RegisterScreen:{screen:RegisterScreen},
    ForgotScreen:{screen:ForgotScreen}
},{
    initialRouteName:'ForgotScreen'
})

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Login:{screen:TAB.Login},
    TabOne:{screen:secondStack},
    TabTwo:{screen:TAB.TabB}
},{
    animationEnabled:true,
    initialRouteName:'Login'
})

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Tabs:{screen:Tabs},
    Stack:{screen:stack}
},
{
    animationEnabled:true,
    initialRouteName:'Tabs'
})
```

hope above code snippet is useful for you.

Comment: When i navigate to other page from tabs, using this.props.navigation then when back button click on header is clicked, it redirects to other page instead of tab. Please if you have any working demo of whole react native application then please can you share it with me?

Comment: > First of all your main issue is you cann't create more than one StackNavigator() on your code.

This is totally wrong.
See, for example, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html